# Longest diagonal in a convex quadrilateral

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

Is is true that, in any convex quadrilateral $\mathcal{Q}$, the longest distance between any two points of $\mathcal{Q}$ is attained when we join two non-adjacent vertices of $\mathcal{Q}$?

I suppose this fact (or its negation) is well-known, but I can't find it in the bibliography I have at hand.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This question could be improved by explaining what "the bibliography (you) have at hand" is, and also why you want to know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that isn't true.
E.g. take the quadrilateral with vertices $(0,0), (1,1), (1,3), (0,4)$.
The longest distance is between $(0,0)$ and $(0,4)$, i.e. two adjacent vertices.

What is true is that the longest distance is between two vertices.
EDIT: I first added that probably these two vertices had acute angles, but this is false.